# Java wider object assignment conversion

Tags: java, casting, reference, field, typing

In the following example, I don't understand why `Base b1 = new Derived();
System.out.println(b1);` prints out `x=10, z=20`. My understanding is that since `b1` has a static type of Base, it don't have access to the fields in `Derived`, so `z` shouldn't haven been printed out. Can someone please help to explain? Many thanks!

```
class Base {
  int x;
  public Base1() { x = 10; }
  public Base1(int x) { this.x =x; }
  public String toString() {
     return "x=" + x ;
  } 
 }
 class Derived1 extends Base1 {
     int z = x * 2;
     public Derived1() {}
     public Derived1(int x, int z) {
        super(x);
        this.z = this.z + z;
     }
     public String toString() {
        return "x=" + x + ", z=" + z;
     }
  }
```

Comment: This is the whole purpose of polymorphism.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *object* is a `Derived`, not a `Base`. Your *interface* to the object from `b1` is `Base`. `Base` has `toString`, so you can access `toString`. The implementation you access is the one the object has, which is provided by `Derived`, which uses `z`. The implementation of `Derived#toString` can access `z` because its reference to the object is via a `Derived` reference (`this`), not a `Base` reference.

As Oli points out in a comment, this is fundamental to polymorphism — having the behavior of the object depend on the object rather than the interface to the object.

If the internals of the object were dictated by the interface we had to it, we'd be in a fair bit of trouble trying to implement `interface`s! :-)

Comment: Thanks! I am still a bit confused, as I remember the teacher says something like: "this wider assignment is ok, but b1 will not have access to the fields in Derived." So what does this refer to? Does it mean that it can access z through method, like you said, but it can't access through b1.z?

Comment: @user3735871: It means that the code using `b1` will only have access to the things defined by `Base`, even though the object is a `Derived`. Those things could be new methods or new fields. As far as the code *using* `b1` is concerned, `b1` is a `Base`. But when the code using `b1` calls a method on the object that's defined by `Base` but implemented by `Derived`, the code within that method has access to everything `Derived` defines. So yes, `b1.z` is inaccessible but `b1.toString` can access `z` because `b1.toString` is implemented by `Derived`.

Comment: Thank you. It makes much more sense now! Just one more question: so if there is no toString method in Base, or i.e. run () method in Base, then the Derived class won't be able to override it to access z ?

Comment: @user3735871: Say you have a `run` method in `Derived` but not in `Base`. You can't access `run` from `b1` directly, because `run` doesn't exist on `Base`, and your interface to the object is defined by `Base`, not `Derived`. Now, if `Base` had a `foo` method, and `Derived` overrode that `foo` method, calling `b1.foo` could call `run` if that's what the `Derived` code for `foo` did (exactly like your `toString`), which is why I said `b1` can't call `run` *directly*.

Comment: Thank you! You explained it really well.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

> A subclass inherits all of the public and protected members of its
>   parent, no matter what package the subclass is in. If the subclass is
>   in the same package as its parent, it also inherits the
>   package-private members of the parent. You can use the inherited
>   members as is, replace them, hide them, or supplement them with new
>   members

In your code you call the default constructor to create a new `Derived1` object : 
`Base b1 = new Derived();`and this in turn calls the default constructor of the parent class where there you happen to set `x = 10`. After that, you go to this line `int z = x * 2;`